# iOS 11.1.2 Date bug crashing in the app

Tags: ios, swift

Recently I'm facing a crash in production on this line
`dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString!)`

> Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
>
> EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001024a89e4

I tried to replicate this issue in development in other version like 10.x and 11.0, 11.2.x, here its not crashing.
But in crashlytics i'm constantly getting crash log of OS 11.1.2

I guess it may be due to [iOS 11.1.2 Date Bug](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/12/02/ios-11-1-2-date-bug-crash-loop/)

want to get it fixed to avoid crashes to iOS 11.1.2 users.

Any help on this to get it fixed will be most appreciated.

Comment: yes its not getting nil - I'm totally sure

Comment: check dateFormat

Comment: @vinod-rathod : The article you posted clearly says you cant do much about it! rather than expecting ur user base to update to 11.2 And if thats the issue not only your app other apps on the users device that uses local notification must also be crashing. In that case user will seek out help from apple and will end up updating his OS. All that you can do is add a if condition to check iOS version and disable local notification feature to iOS 11.1.2

Answer (score 0):

this problem occur when the date formatter is not coming according to you which you write in code please change date formatter